# Crear array dimensional en Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, array

**Necesito crear un array de esta forma:**

```
data: [
         ['Enero 2020', 24.2],
         ['Febrero 2020', 20.8],
         ['Marzo 2020', 14.9],
         ['Abril 2020', 13.7]
      ]
```

**Estuve probando pero lo único que consigo es esto:**

```
for(var i = 0; i < historialConsumo.length; i++){
      nuevoArray[historialConsumo[i].MesFacturado] = historialConsumo[i].MesTotal;
}
```

**A lo maximo que he llegado fue a este tipo de array:**

```
(4) ["S/. 0.00", "S/. 0.00", "S/. 11.20", "S/. 11.10"]

0: "S/. 0.00"
1: "S/. 0.00"
2: "S/. 11.20"
3: "S/. 11.10"
length: 4
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

podrías intentarlo de la siguiente manera, tal vez te pueda seguir de guía como crear un array dimensional.

```js
var x = new Array(4);
var meses = ['enero','febrero','marzo','abril'];
var dinero = ['10','20','30','40'];
for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
  x[i] = new Array(meses[i],dinero[i]);
}

console.log(x);
```

Comment: Gracias, es justo lo que buscaba.

Answer (score 0):

En principio te recomiendo en vez del for utilizar la función map. Esto
También itera sobre un array. Te dejo el link de referencia:

https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/map

Por lo que veo en la data final a la que deberías arribar, es un array de arrays. Según lo que has logrado obtener, no estás armando arrays de arrays. Tampoco se ve qué esté tomando bien los meses. Podrías mostrar como armaste esa parte?

Luego deberás utilizar la función push para ingresar esos arrays en un array.

Te dejo también la referencia de push:

https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/push

Habría que ver como te dan los datos iniciales para dar una respuesta exacta pero ya veo que en otros comentarios te dieron el código bien hecho, sólo quería sumarte recursos!